# PHP htmlentities or htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

I'm using fwrite to create an xml file but i'm losing the special the characters.

Example:

```
$message0  = htmlspecialchars('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
$file = fopen("test.xml","w");
echo fwrite($file,"$message0");
fclose($file);
```

The above code gives me the following output

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;JobTemplates&gt;
```

I need the special characters in order for the xml file to work. If i echo the variables, the special characters appear on the page.

Comment: Why are you running `htmlspecialchars` on the header?

Comment: because of the special characters in the string. If i do $message0 = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"; the output is blank.

Comment: Oh I see. Use single quotes. `$message0 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';`

Comment: i tried that already, its not going to work with single quotes or double because they have special values in php. Thats why htmlentities and htmlspecialchars was created

Comment: You are echoing fwrite. fwrite returns the number of bytes or false on error. PHP interprets single quotes as literal text so no interpretation is done on the string.

Comment: I guess i'm not explaining this enough. $message = "<<<>>>"; echo $message will return a blank result. $message = '<><><'; will also return a blank result. $message = htmlspecialchars('<><><'); $echo will give you <><>< and if you use fwrite the results will give you '&lt;'. I dont need to echo anything. I'm just using it to show you guys what the results are.

Comment: It's not clear if you're wanting to see the XML in the browser or if you want to edit the file and see the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not understanding why you're encoding html characters for this. It's a trusted string, so, just put it in single quotes and write it. If any character's are giving you trouble, escape them instead of encoding them.

If there's a reason you must do it this way, then decode inline. But it all seems a bit messy to me.

Comment: Not sure why Escape vs Encode was downvoted,...but there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tested example , you should not use htmlspecialchars

```
$message0  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><contact><name>foo</name><phone>123456</phone></contact>';
$file = fopen("test.xml","w");
fwrite($file,$message0);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: there's a dynamic input field on the form being used to generate the xml file. I was only getting the last value on the form instead of everything. Thanks to everyone contributing i figured it out. Thank you guys, sorry for the confusion.